# remove soap header WCF SOAP service

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, soap, soapheader

I know there are many answers to do with this but I am still confused as many don't go into detail on their services.svc class or their web config

I would like to know how to empty a soap header which has nothing inside it

so from this

```
<s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/PiMetadataRequest</Action>
</s:Header>
```

to just

```
<s:Header/>
```

I like to do this in the web config but if not, any help will do.

Comment: This usually happens with SOAP 1.1, you can try using SOAP 1.2. modifying your web.config and adding these lines to your configuration node: <webServices>
<protocols>
<remove name="HttpSOAP"/>
<add name="HttpSOAP12>
</protocols>
</webServices>

Comment: Cheers but doesn't work, WCF complains it cannot read protocols

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but maybe this [link](http://trycatch.me/adding-custom-message-headers-to-a-wcf-service-using-inspectors-behaviors/) is useful for you.
You could try clearing the Headers of the Message object like Message.Headers.Clear();